# Erro instalar plugin Font Awesome

Tags: html5, css3

entao pessoal ja tentei fazer de td, instalei os icones da maneira correta como o site fala para fazer

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css">
```

para add o icone estou colocando

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

no site aparece assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em que diretoria está o ficheiro de HTML e o ficheiro de CSS?

Comment: estao todos dentro de uma pasta chamada portifolio2 e o arquivo font-awesome.min esta dentro desta pasta

Comment: engraçado que usando cdn o icone esta funcionando

Comment: E o ficheiro de CSS que chama o font-awesome também está nessa pasta?

Comment: acho que eu nao chamei o font-awesome no ficheiro css, estou usando sass como que faço?

Comment: O CSS chama os arquivos de fonte (`.FontAwesome.otf`, por exemplo)  dentro dele, veja se o caminho definido dentro do CSS estão correspondente aos arquivos de fonte. Veja no console se esses arquivos são obtidos ou resultam em erro.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você fez de tudo mas não instalou as fonts.
Crie uma pasta chamada fonts/ e uma chamada css/
coloque o font-awesome.min.css dentro de css/
e coloque as fonts dentro de fonts/
- Vai ficar +/- assim:

```
/css/font-awesome.min.css  
/fonts/FontAwesome.otf  
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot  
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg  
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf  
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff  
/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

**Veja só a hierarquia no link**
[CdnJs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome)